# Having Issues with Grading Logic for Quiz App Android Studio

Tags: java, android, logic

Having issues with my grading logic, can't seem to cap the integer value at ten and not sure why my logic is adding up to weird values, etc.

XML Files

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/custom_toast"
    android:background="#e7e7e7">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/question1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Question 1: What kind of noodles are used in pho?"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    />

    <RadioGroup  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_spaghetti"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Spaghetti"
            android:onClick="firstRadioButtons"/>
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_udon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Udon"
            android:onClick="firstRadioButtons"/>
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_rice"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Rice Noodles"
            android:onClick="firstRadioButtons"/>
</RadioGroup>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/question2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Question 2: What country did pho originate from?"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    />
    <RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_vietnam"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Vietnam"
            android:onClick="secondRadioButtons"/>
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_japan"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Japan"
            android:onClick="secondRadioButtons"/>
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_australia"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Australia"
            android:onClick="secondRadioButtons"/>
    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/question3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Question 3: What are some common vegetables in pho?"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        />

    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/checkbox_onion"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Onions"
        android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>

    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/checkbox_bean_sprouts"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Bean Sprouts"
        android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>

    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/checkbox_broccoli"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Broccoli"
        android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>

    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/checkbox_spinach"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Spinach"
        android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/question4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Question 4: What is a spicy, chili sauce that can be added to pho?"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/text_input"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:onClick="fillInTheBlank"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/question5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Question 5: Is pho considered a..."
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        />

    <RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_soup"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Soup"
            android:onClick="lastRadioButtons"/>
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_sandwich"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sandwich"
            android:onClick="lastRadioButtons"/>
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_dessert"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Dessert"
            android:onClick="lastRadioButtons"/>
    </RadioGroup>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/toast_results"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
        android:fontFamily="monospace"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:onClick="finalScore"
        android:text="Are you pho-real, or not?" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/reset"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:fontFamily="monospace"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:onClick="resetScore"
        android:text="Reset Score" />
```

Java File

```
package com.example.android.quizapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
int points = 0;
Button button;
Text message;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.toast_results);
}

//Question one
public void firstRadioButtons(View view) {
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.radio_spaghetti:
            if (checked)
                points += 0;
        case R.id.radio_udon:
            if (checked)
                points += 0;
        case R.id.radio_rice:
            if (checked)
                points += 2;
    }
}

//Question two
public void secondRadioButtons(View view) {
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.radio_vietnam:
            if (checked)
                points += 2;
        case R.id.radio_japan:
            if (checked)
                points += 0;
        case R.id.radio_australia:
            if (checked)
                points += 0;
    }
}

//Question three
public void onCheckboxClicked(View view) {

    CheckBox cb1 = findViewById(R.id.checkbox_onion);
    CheckBox cb2 = findViewById(R.id.checkbox_bean_sprouts);
    CheckBox cb3 = findViewById(R.id.checkbox_broccoli);
    CheckBox cb4 = findViewById(R.id.checkbox_spinach);
    if (cb1.isChecked() && cb2.isChecked()) {
        points += 2.0;
    } else if (cb1.isChecked() && cb3.isChecked()) {
        points += 1;
    } else if (cb1.isChecked() && cb4.isChecked()) {
        points += 1;
    } else if (cb2.isChecked() && cb3.isChecked()) {
        points += 1;
    } else if (cb2.isChecked() && cb4.isChecked()) {
        points += 1;
    } else if (cb3.isChecked() && cb4.isChecked()) {
        points += 0;
    }
}


//Question Five
public void lastRadioButtons(View view) {
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.radio_soup:
            if (checked)
                points += 2;
        case R.id.radio_sandwich:
            if (checked)
                points += 0;
        case R.id.radio_dessert:
            if (checked)
                points += 0;
    }
}

//Calculate final Score and display
public void finalScore(View view) {

    String q4 = "Sriracha";

    EditText questionFive = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text_input);
    String questionFiveAnswer = questionFive.getText().toString();
    if (questionFiveAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase(q4)) {
        points += 2;
    }

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, points + " out of 10 ",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        {
            String message = points + " out of 10 ";

            if (points == 2) {
                message += "Pho? No.";
            } else if (points == 4) {
                message += "Ok, so you've had it once";
            } else if (points == 6) {
                message += "You're getting there! ";
            } else if (points == 7) {
                message += "Almost Pho-lly there!";
            } else if (points == 8) {
                message += "Pho-real! You're great!";
            } else if (points == 10) {
                message += "Pho-tastic!! Expert!";

            }

        }
    }

// Reset the quiz score
public void resetScore (View view){
    points = 0;
}
```

I know it's probably way overcomplicated and too long, but I'm a beginner, cut me some slack! It runs fine, but I just don't know where I'm going wrong or what I can look for to make it run more streamlined with accurate logic.